# how to copy and edit data from nsdictionary to plist?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, plist, nsdictionary

I want to copy my NSDictionary's data into plist and also edit some data which are into the plist .So , how should I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSMutableDictionary`'s `+dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:` to read the plist and be able to edit it.

Then to write it to a file use `-writeToFile:atomically:`

This is all clearly outlined in the [`NSDictionary` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Always consult the documentation before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Use `writeToFile:atomically:` to write the dictionary in your document directory and if you want to edit it then get the dictionary using `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:` edit it and then save it again using `writeToFile:atomically:`.
overwriting may cause some problem but if problem comes you can remove the file first then write it again.